# Submit and Show Data using jQuery - issue

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I'm trying to submit form data without refreshing the page using jQuery. I've added all the following code in correct places but the page refreshes and nothing happened, neither it echo's the success data nor it inserts any data into sql db. Here is what I'm trying to do;

### HTML:

```
        $profile_comments = '
        <form action="#" method="post">
            <table border="0" cellspacing="'.$theme['borderwidth'].'" cellpadding="'.$theme['tablespace'].'" class="sideboxes_tborder">
                <tr>
                    <td class="sideboxes_thead">Post Comments</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="sideboxes_trow">
                        <input type="text" class="textbox_comment" name="message" id="pc_message" tabindex="1" autocomplete="off" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="sideboxes_trow" align="left">
                        <input type="hidden" name="uid" value="'.$memprofile['uid'].'" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="from_uid" value="'.$mybb->user['uid'].'" />
                        <input type="submit" class="button" id="comment_submit" name="submit" value="Post Comment" tabindex="2">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="sideboxes_trow"><div id="show_profile_comments" style="overflow: auto; max-height: 313px;"></div></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>';
```

### jQuery:

```
jQuery.noConflict();

jQuery(document).ready(function($)
{
    $("#comment_submit").click(function()
    {

            var message = $( "#pc_message" ).val(),

            if (message == '')
            {
                alert( "Message is missing!!" );
                return;
            }

            $.ajax(
            {
                type : "post",
                dataType: "html",
                url : "pro_profile.php?action=do_comment",
                data : "message=" + message,
                success : function(response)
                {
                    $('#show_profile_comments').html(response);
                }
                document.getElementById('pc_message').value = '';
                document.getElementById('pc_message').focus();

                if (response.error)
                {
                    alert(response.error);
                }
            });
    });
});
```

### PHP:

```
if ($_POST['action'] == "do_comment")
{
    $uid = intval($mybb->input['uid']);
    $insert_array = array(
        "uid" => $uid,
        "from_uid" => intval($mybb->input['from_uid']),
        "approved" => '1',
        "message" => $db->escape_string($mybb->input['message']),
        "dateline" => TIME_NOW
    );
    $db->insert_query("pp_comments", $insert_array);

    $query = $db->simple_select("pp_comments", "*", "uid='{$uid}'");
    $c = $db->fetch_array($query);

    echo $c['message'];
}
```

Please help!

Comment: in your jQuery part, did you get value into message variable and if its empty did it show alert message?

Comment: No it doesn't alerting if the message input box is empty either :s

Comment: Give your form an id="msgSubmit" and in your jquery replace var message = $( "#pc_message" ).val(),

            if (message == '')
            {
                alert( "Message is missing!!" );
                return;
            } with  var datastring = $("#msgSubmit").serialize(); and then alert this datastring. and let me know you are getting msg or not? because most of this happens with me if i use $ multiple time nothing happens.

Comment: No it doesn't alert either.. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if this should be on success

> document.getElementById('pc_message').value = '';
>
> document.getElementById('pc_message').focus();

change your JS code to this

```
jQuery.noConflict();

jQuery(document).ready(function($)
{
    $("#comment_submit").on('click', function()
    {

            var message = $( "#pc_message" ).val(),

            if (message == '')
            {
                alert( "Message is missing!!" );
                return;
            }

            $.ajax(
            {
                type : "post",
                dataType: "html",
                url : "pro_profile.php?action=do_comment",
                data : "message=" + message,
                success : function(response)
                {
                    $('#show_profile_comments').html(response);
                    document.getElementById('pc_message').value = '';
                document.getElementById('pc_message').focus();
                },
            error : function(response)
                {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            });
            
            return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just because you are using click event on submit buttton

replace

```
<input type="submit" class="button" id="comment_submit" name="submit" value="Post Comment" tabindex="2">
```

with

```
<input type="button" class="button" id="comment_submit" name="submit" value="Post Comment" tabindex="2">
```

Comment: Its not a issue Deepak, I've tried your suggestion but it doesn't works.

Comment: No it doesn't alerting if the message input box is empty either :s

Comment: ok remove form from you code <form> remove opening form and closing form you don't need it. then check its alerting or not

Comment: I've removed opening and closing form tags and it doesn't alerting either.

Answer (score 0):

change your button from submit type to button type

```
<input type="button" class="button" id="comment_submit" name="submit" value="Post Comment" tabindex="2">
```

or prevent Default form submit

```
$("#yourFormName").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

use [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$("#buttonId").on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
  });
```

**[e.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)**

Description: If this method is called, the default action of the event will not be triggered.

it's ok either button or submit

```
<input type="submit" class="button" id="comment_submit" name="submit" value="Post Comment" tabindex="2">
```

Answer (score 0):

Just changed the `type` for the button

`<input type="button" class="button" id="comment_submit" name="submit" value="Post Comment" tabindex="2">`

or just make it as a button:

`<button type="button" class="button" id="comment_submit" name="submit">Post Comment</button>`

or in the `<form>` if it has an `id`:

```
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery("#yourform").submit(function(e) {       
      e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

or in the form tag

`<form type="post" onclick="return false"`>

Comment: What doesnt work? that it is the way to stop a page from submit a form

Comment: I've tried both ways, by using `input type="button"` as well as `<button ..>` neither of them works. I've also tried with the edited jquery you suggested but unfortunately it doesn't work either.

Comment: can you post the rest of the html? because that it is a really odd behavior :S

Comment: I can't since this comment box here doesn't allow me to post more then 550 characters. Anyway the HTML is same as I posted in question above.

Comment: try `onclick="return false"` in the form tag

Comment: I think its not the issue. IMO the jquery I used have some issues but due to my lack of jquery knowledge I'm unable to find the error. Please help

Comment: well tell me what errors do you have in the console, do you get any php errors?